# I am having problems creating a new project in adonis in windows 8 (error message inside)

Tags: node.js, web, adonis.js

Below is an adonis error that reports with execution with the "adonis new yardstick" command
[certain adonis.js error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NAd8.png)

I ask this because I am at a loss at what to do, I thought toe problem was no install gthub because the command isues to seems to derive from "git". Sorry if this is a simple fix but I cannot for the life of me find a working solution

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your git configuration. That's not a problem with Adonis itself.